# Hide certain images from certain users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

**It seems impossible to make certain images private with Rails**. I've searched high, I've searched low, I've asked here on SO. Got a few upvotes, but no solid response. No tutorials online. Nothing. Bags of tutorials on how to store images in the assets folder, but nothing to make images private.

Let's say I have three types of user, `typeA`, `typeB` and `typeC`. And let's say I have three types of images. So database schema would be as follows:

*images*

```
=> ["image_path","blob","type"]
```

*users*

```
=> ["name","type"]
```

**What I want is that the users can request only the following:**

*typeA*:

> ***Can** only view images with a type of A*
>
> ***Cannot** view images with a type of B*
>
> ***Cannot** only view images with a type of C*

*typeB*:

> ***Can** only view images with a type of B*
>
> ***Cannot** view images with a type of A*
>
> ***Cannot** only view images with a type of C*

*typeC*:

> ***Can** only view images with a type of C*
>
> ***Cannot** view images with a type of A*
>
> ***Cannot** only view images with a type of B*

And yes, I could have given you the example with two types of user and image, but I really want to make sure you understand the problem; the actual system I have in mind will have hundreds of `types`.

I mean, I can do this in the view:

```
<% if current_user.type == image.type do %>
   <%= image_tag image.path #=> <img src="/assets/typaAImage.jpg" alt="..." class="..."> %>
<% end %>
```

but someone who isn't even a user can simply request `/assets/typeAImage.jpg.` and get at the image, so I really don't know what to do.

**Can I prevent people browsing the public assets directory? Stop all access to the directory apart from the application itself?**

**If not, how can I make the images private?**

I'd like answers for:

Doing this on Heroku. (postgres )

Doing this on a VPS ( postgres, **nginx** )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I personally do:

Keep the private images in a special folder, NOT under `public`.

Serve them through Rails, NOT through Nginx/Apache. Like this:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def get_secret_photo
    if current_user.has_the_right_permissions?
      send_file(File.join(Rails.root, 'special_folder', 'image_name.png'))
    else
      render status: :forbidden, nothing: true
    end
  end
end
```

Problem solved!

Comment: Wow, that's so much simpler than I thought it would be :)

Comment: So the `send_file` method can be used to show images via an `<img />` tag? I thought it was for initiating a download of the image... (you know what I mean, into the downloads folder)

Comment: Hi, @Starkers! Do you know what an `<img>` tag actually does? It tells your browser, "make a request for this file, and then display it in this web page". What the `send_file` method does: it reads a file from the hard drive, and puts the contents of that file in the body of your HTTP response. That may initiate a "download" in some contexts, yes, but it's also exactly what is needed for an `<img>`. It is no different from what Apache/Nginx/etc. do when returning an image file in an HTTP response.

Comment: Ah okay this seems like a good plan. For the +250 bounty, do you reckon you could show me how to correctly implement this? I gather I'd have to have a custom route that would link to the above action for example..

Comment: Yes, you will need a route. Probably you will want to pass the image name in as a parameter. What else did I miss?